# Can the mouse pointer be made to stop at the edge of a Xinerama screen?

Tags: gnome, mouse, multi-monitor, xinerama

I've got 3 monitors set up with Xinerama (not using XRandR) running GNOME. The monitors don't form a rectangle, and I'm having a problem with the mouse behaviour when I try to move the mouse into an area where there's no monitor. Instead of stopping dead at the edge of the monitor it's on, as I'd prefer, it leaps to somewhere on a nearby monitor it can find.

Here's my layout:

```
+---------+                 +---------+
|      a->|                 |<-c      |
|         |+---------------+|         |
|         ||a'->       <-c'||         |
|         ||               ||         |
|         ||b'->       <-d'||         |
|         |+---------------+|         |
|      b->|                 |<-d      |
+---------+                 +---------+
```

If I move the mouse right at point a, where the GNOME user menu is, instead of stopping, it jumps to point a'. And if moving left at point c, where a menu bar usually is, it jumps to point c'. And, similarly, for point b (where the workspace switcher is) and d.

I can see the reason for this feature, but I'm finding it difficult to get used to. I'd much rather the mouse just stopped. Can I make it do that?

System is `Linux tlinux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, default proprietary NVidia driver from debian stable, GNOME 3.4.2 in fallback mode.